# Marginal PDF given Marginal Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

The marginal distribution of $X$ is $U(0, 1)$.  The conditional distribution of $Y$, given $X = x$, is $U(0, e^x)$.

Find $f(y)$, the marginal PDF of $Y$ and give its support.

This should be a simple problem, but every time I attempt it I keep getting the wrong pdf for $Y$.  I end up with:

$$f(y) = 1 - \frac1e$$ 
on $$0 < y < \frac e{e-1}.$$

But this doesn't seem to be quite right.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

For the joint PDF, I obtained:
$$f(x, y) = e^{-x}$$
on
$$0<x<1\ and \ 0 < y < e^x $$

Comment: Perhaps show some details of your work so that the mistake can be detected. For example, what is the joint PDF of $(X,Y)$ and what is the support of $(X,Y)$?

Comment: Thanks for editing with the intermediate work. Now picturing that support, when you are looking for the marginal of $Y$, one would be going across horizontally for some $y$. That is, integration would be $dx$ running from $x=\ln y$ to $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You're answer is fine. I'm not sure why it wouldn't make sense. I'm assuming you integrated across all x values (0 to 1) of $f$$($$y$$|$$x$$)$$f$$($$x$$)$ to get your answer. Normalising gives the range you specify.

Comment: -1. Can you provide the details confirming the OP's $pdf$ and the support for the marginal of $Y$ are correct?

Comment: $f(y|x) = e^{-x}$, $f(x) = 1$.

Comment: That is the easy part of writing down the given information. Then how specifically do you get the marginal PDF of $Y$? What are the limits of integration? What is the support of $Y$?